# Disabling SearchView

Tags: android, search, android-widget

I'm trying to disable a `SearchView` from my `Activity`. I tried the following code :

```
    mSearchView.setEnabled(false);
    mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
    mSearchView.setClickable(false);
```

But it does not work. SearchView can still be clicked and KeyBoard popps up. I want it to become greyed out and unclickable. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: i think this is a better solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/42074814/5490632

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None of the stated answers were sufficient for my needs, so I would like to provide another one for anybody in the same situation.

[image: SearchView, has focus, has search and clear button]

A SearchView is made up of different Views, which can be - and in this case have to be - addressed individually.
If you want your SearchView (support v7) to freeze and grey out in a state like this, not answering to any kind of input, including the search and clear button, you can use:

```
ImageView clearButton = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchEditText = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

clearButton.setEnabled(false);
searchEditText.setEnabled(false);
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
```

( Besides, I got an issue with deeptis answer `searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)`: If you disable the SearchView this way and click it afterwards, the system seemingly expects an open keyboard though the keyboard isn't shown. Therefore, the first back button click causes nothing but closing the - not shown or not in fact opened - keyboard. )

Answer (score 6):

To disable any view (e.g. `SearchView`) either set its `input-type` to `none` in layout XML or call `view.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)` from the `Activity`.

Comment: How to enable it again ? @Deepti

Answer (score 2):

You can also hide the searchView completely.
You can hide the searchview and the searchicon by doing this:

```
    searchItem.setVisible(false);
    searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Then you can bring it back by:

```
    searchItem.setVisible(true);
    searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

From @outta comfort's answer, here is my solution:

```
private void enableSearchView(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            enableSearchView(child, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

In other place, call this:

```
enableSearchView(searchView, true/false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To Clear SearchView Focus :

```
searchView.clearFocus();
```

To Hide SearchView :

```
searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: How can visibility GONE and clearFocus be the answer to "I want it to become greyed out and unclickable."