# How to disable searchview?

Tags: android, searchview

Can you help me on how to disable searchview when button is pressed? I'm trying this code:

```
searchView.setEnabled(false);
                searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                searchView.clearFocus();
```

but it seems not working. I can still input text in searchview.

Thanks.. :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
searchView.clearFocus();
```

and if you want to hide it using:

```
searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 14):

All above questions don't work for me.
Becase SearchView is a ViewGroup, so we have to disable all its child views.

```
private void enableSearchView(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            enableSearchView(child, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

In other place, call this:

```
enableSearchView(searchView, true/false);
```

Comment: IMO the best solution

Comment: Worked for me. Smart approach.

Comment: best answer. here is the same implementation in a kotlin extension:

`fun View.setEnabledAllChilds(enabled: Boolean) {
    isEnabled = false
    if (this is ViewGroup) {
        this.forEachChild { it.setEnabledAllChilds(enabled) }
    }
}`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
searchview.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

`SearchView` isn't the actual `EditText` you type into, but rather is a `LinearLayout` which holds a bunch of views, including the `EditText`.

To get the view you actually want for disabling it:

```
EditText searchViewEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
```

Note, this only works if you're using support v7 `SearchView`, since the particular resource id is internal if you use the framework `SearchView`.

Answer (score 1):

```
searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_button).setEnabled(false);
```

But you must check it for null and hide searchView:

```
ImageView searchBtn = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_button);
if (searchBtn != null) searchBtn.setEnabled(false);
searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I think this will work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

`searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` ?

Comment: Actually, I try that one.. But i want to disable the searchview (grey out) where the user cannot input a text.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
    searchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Don't perform any action.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

Comment: if you are using android.support.v7.widget.SearchView, to close searchview   first call of setIconified, text is cleared, second call of setIconified, keyboard and search view get closed.

Comment: Edit your answer and add any description to it so that it will help others to understand the reason why it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener( new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus && !v.isEnabled()) v.clearFocus();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, it is always good to describe why/how the answer will provide a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
val searchEditText: EditText =
        searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
    searchEditText.isEnabled=false
```

This will work

Answer (score -1):

If you want to clear it (SearchView), do:

`searchView.clearFocus();`

and if you want to hide it temporarily, do:

`searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Hi, I want in my searchview to be disable(it looks grey out) when the user pressed the button.

Comment: Am not sure there is a method to do that directly, but you can try something like using an if statement where you call:

searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

if a button is pressed.

Comment: Actually. that's the one I try first. But thanks for comment.