# App's hierarchy within bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I want to implement `bottomNavigationBar`. in that when i click on any item within `fragment`, it should open new view with `bottomNavigationBar` at bottom and back button on top like below screen.

[image]

there is also other example from below link:
[View](https://androiduipatterns.com/on-the-bottom-navigation-bar-d07d9b4b5e18)

in that, you can see you-tube did same thing with `searchView`. help me how can i do that.

Comment: Will this be of any help? http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/    OR this https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0

Comment: @Stallion i already did R&D around 6 to 7 hours on it.. and also visited all this link.. but not found anything..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     @Override
  .  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmet_search, parent, false);
        return v;
    }


        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_search_menu_xml, menu);
           super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }
```

> [@FAT Suggestions Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351487/how-to-create-bottom-navigation-bar-similar-to-instagram)

This may help you.